# Weird characters Helvetica Neue "st" on Android

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts

I'm getting a weird character on Android devices (not IOS) when I enter a text in Helvetica Neue on my website in a paragraph. It creates a weird kind of swirl between the two letters. Does anyone know why or how to fix this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It's [a feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature), not a bug.

Comment: I don't think it is a feature, deceze: https://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/neue-helvetica

Comment: @Michel It's certainly not a rendering bug or something. That ligature is being put there by something on purpose. Even if it's unwanted.

Comment: @deceze True that :)

Comment: Perhaps you could use this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591746/prevent-ligatures-in-safari-mavericks-ios7-via-css

Comment: Or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39504775/1016716). Or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38926144/css-disable-font-ligatures-in-all-browsers). Or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37226949/1016716).

Comment: For what it's worth, this `st` ligature is a "discretionary ligature" (or "historical ligature"), as opposed to "standard ligatures" like `fl`, `fi` or `ff`- which can be enabled or disabled separately via Opentype features, e.g. CSS.